# Office 365: Graph API and Office Graph

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a question about SharePoint Online, Office Graph and Graph API.

Today, the Office Graph option is deactivated in my tenant (SharePoint admin center > Settings and under Office Graph, "Don’t allow access to the Office Graph" option is selected) for security reasons.
I would like to know if it is possible to write some code with Graph API when this option is off?

Thanks a lot in advance for answers.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ok, also you can try the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) to Test your code without log into Microsoft account

[image]